# What does self.rect.midbottom mean here? and what does the screen.blit() do here?

Tags: python

This is the a py module

```
import pygame
class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        ## Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        ## Start each new ship at the bottom centre of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

the screen.blit() should be like screen.blit(background, (x, y), but I don't see any coordinate here... and is the background the image I load??? this code is an example from my guidebook...

Answer (score 0):

`self.rect.midbottom` returns the point at the center of the bottom of the rectangle.  `self.screen.blit` copies the given image onto the screen at the coordinates in the rectangle.  This is just modeling a single ship; there's nothing here about the screen or its background.

Comment: is self.rect.midbottom an attribute???? if it is, shouldn't it be like self.rect_midbottom? what does the dot behind rect do here? This is where I am confused

Comment: It's exactly the same as `self.screen.blit` and `ai_screen.screen`.  `self` contains the name `rect`.  `self.rect` contains a rectangle object. That object has a property called `midbottom`.